# Declarative authorization with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, declarative-authorization

I'm coming here as a last resort, tried everything.Its just not working. So here goes.

Here is my authorization code:

```
role :department_admin do
#Department has many users through designations  
  has_permission_on [:departments], :to => [:manage] do
    if_attribute :designations => contains {user.designation}
  end
  has_permission_on :users, :to => [:read]
  has_permission_on :users, :to => [:create, :update, :destroy] do
    if_permitted_to :manage, :department
  end
```

My Controller code for departments:

```
filter_resource_access
#and the rest
```

And in users_controller :

```
filter_resource_access :nested_in => :departments
# and the rest
```

I'm trying to follow the pattern used in the example app given on the declarative_authorization github page, but in vain.

So with this configuration when I try to create a new user

I get

```
Couldn't find Department without an ID
```

Any head's up or a tip could really help.

Comment: Can you verify that the department ID is included in the route?

Comment: Yes it is. Anyway I switched to Cancan and its awesome !